# How can I restrict search results to certain sections of an RTD manual?

Tags: read-the-docs

We use RTD to produce the documentation for our project. The documentation consists of two broad parts: book-style chapters & sections on the one hand, and auto-generated documentation extracted from the code on the other.

We find that often one wants to search only one of the two, but not both at the same time. Is there a way to set this up, or a clever use of an existing mechanism that would do this? A kind of keyword or specifier in the search box would be ideal.

For reference: the [full documentation](https://docs.zeek.org/en/master/) and the [auto-generated part](https://docs.zeek.org/en/master/script-reference/scripts.html).

Comment: We do this in [Plone 6 Documentation](https://6.dev-docs.plone.org/search.html). Open source software. GitHub repo is linked in the upper right.

Comment: Have you took a look at https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/advanced-search.html? There are some special syntax that you can may use for your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently this isn't possible, but we are taking it into consideration https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/5966.

In the meantime, Steve's solution [How can I restrict search results to certain sections of an RTD manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269482/how-can-i-restrict-search-results-to-certain-sections-of-an-rtd-manual#comment131218047_74269482) is a great workaround. They are using a patched version of Sphinx's searchtools.js https://github.com/plone/documentation/blob/7dc58219ee75129831a481f24849defcd8b290bd/docs/_static/searchtools.js#L225-L231.

Another solution, similar to the above, can be achieved using our API https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/server-side-search.html#get--api-v2-search- and filtering the results client side (this is using the `path` attribute of each result)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate it! I had just started to dig into searchtools.js. We'll take a look.